# Okta multi-factor authentication at both org and app level

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml, okta, multi-factor-authentication

I have assigned the AWS app to my Okta account and configured MFA at both the org and app level. I successfully implemented MFA with API's at the org level in the following way:

1. POST Username and Password JSON request to `/api/v1/authn` and receive the state token and factor details in the response.
2. If the response contains "MFA Required", then use the factor details received in step 1 and call `/api/v1/authn/factors/:fid/verify` and get the session token in response.

This completes the org level authentication. I then call the AWS app with the session token received in the above step for app level - `https://<AWS APP URL>?onetimetoken='SessionToken'`. Now this takes me to the login page again. If I repeat the steps 1 and 2, then org level MFA is being done again and not app level MFA.

Any pointers in implementing app level MFA?

Answer (score 0):

Okta does not currently have an API for doing app level MFA. That said, you could still technically add support for app level MFA by implementing a HTTP user agent in code that is aware of the MFA prompt that Okta presents.

If you are an Okta customer and would like API support for app level MFA, I suggest reaching out to your support contact at Okta so they can pass your request along to Okta's product team.